# Line integral using Green's theorem with a singularity in (x,y) = (0,0)

Tags: integration, vector-fields, greens-theorem, singularity

I'm trying to resolve this line integral who has a vector field with a singularity so with Green's theorem, using that the curl = 1 it's very difficult.

My curve is $$C(t) = (3/2\cos(t) - \cos^2(t) , 3/2 \sin(t)- \cos(t)\sin(t))$$
where $$0 \le t \le 2\pi$$
and my vector field is

$$ \int_C \left(\frac{6y}{4x^2 + 9y^2} -y \right)dx + \left(\frac{-6x}{4x^2 + 9y^2} \right)dy $$

Please this is a typical exam problem and I can't figure out how to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If curl(F) = 0 it would be easier so it is a conservative field and I know how to face exercises like that. But the curl(f) is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

You can check that this curve $C$ can be represented by $r=\frac{3}{2}-\cos t$. It is a heart shape with the tip on the left at $(-\frac{5}{2})$.

The ellipse $4x^2+9y^2=1$ is inside it. Let this be $C_1$. Then we can use Green's theorem in the region $D$ enclosed by $C$ and $C_1$. So 
$$\int_C \left(\frac{6y}{4x^2 + 9y^2} -y \right)dx + \left(\frac{-6x}{4x^2 + 9y^2} \right)dy=\int_{C_1}\left(\frac{6y}{4x^2 + 9y^2} -y \right)dx + \left(\frac{-6x}{4x^2 + 9y^2} \right)+\iint_D Q_x-P_y dxdy.$$

Since $Q_x-P_y=1$, the last integral is the area of $D$, which can be found by subtracting from the area of the region enclosed by the curve $C$ the area of the ellipse:

$$\iint_D dxdy =\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{3/2-\cos t}rdrdt-\pi \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{3}\right).$$

The integral on $C_1$ can be done directly.